# Bootloader and Boards Definition for Atmega2560V-8AU at 8 MHz / 3.3v

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, bootloader, atmega2560

I am working on a home made project,where i am using Atmega2560V-8AU **(note the suffix, this part has an 8 MHz maximum clock rate)** as my main controller, supplying 3.3V to this chip.

I want this controller to work exactly same as standard Atmega2560-16AU like on Arduino Mega(perhaps at a slower baud rate on account of the slower clock)

Does there already exist a suitable bootloader image and board definition for an ATmega2560 operating from an 8 MHz crystal?

If not, what changes would need to be made to the usual 16 MHz bootloader and boards definition to support 8 MHz operation, both for the bootloader and for correct time functions and serial buad rates in sketches?

Comment: @Gerben - how do you propose the lower clock speed be handled?  If you are suggesting there is already an option for it, mentioning that would be clearer.

Comment: @Gerben - you seem to be ignoring the whole point of the question - the poster wants to use an **atypical chip** which **cannot operate at the normal clock rate**.  It either needs a custom bootloader to operate at a usual baud rate, or programming support for a slower baud rate.   Your responses so far have been the exact opposite of helpful.

Comment: In actual fact, the ordinary bootloader *will* work, but the problem will come when then trying to talk to it - it will be operating at half the expected baud rate due to the 8 MHz vs expected 16 MHz clock, so the usual board definitions won't allow the IDE to talk to it.  What the poster needs is a good board definition package for an 8 MHz Arduino Mega.

Comment: There is a fair amount of coverage here and elsewhere for 8 MHz / 3.3v usage of the ATMega328p - the situation with the 2560 will be similar enough that those solutions could be used as a model for the necessary modifications or workarounds, but of course an ATMega328p board package won't actually work on a 2560.

Comment: Hello,
I am sorry for not providing enough information my task! I am using 8Mhz crystal and the chip runs on 3.3V, I cannot upload bootloaders of Atmega2560-16AU which runs on 16Mhz cystal.

Yes! the ordinary boorloaders should work! but i need to change 16Mhz set to 8Mhz set somewhere in some files of ARduino IDE

How do i dot that.? and is there any more things i have to do like Fuses etc.?

and I am using my Arduino UNO as "Arduino as ISP" programmer in the list, which will have +5V on the SPI lines and I am running my target chip on 3.3V, 
Does it hurts to my chip.?

Thank you

Comment: Sparkfun used to sell a board with this chip, and seems to still have downloadable resource at https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10744 however, the way the Arduino IDE does things has changed over time, and those files may not work with a current one.  I believe there is now some drop-down menu support for various clock options for some boards, so that may be an alternate route.

Comment: thank you for reply,
I have tested with the above mentioned Sparkfun board with the files on bootloaders, But the board is not showing in the boards section.

Is there any chance of customising stock Arduino Mega bootloaders with this chip.?
Thank you

Comment: As I said, the way the Arduino handles board definitions keeps changing, so it unsurprising that the old one doesn't work with a recent IDE.  You'll need to find our figure out how to make a definition for a modern IDE (perhaps using the old one and new ones for an 8 MHz ATmega328p as guides), or (less preferably) use an old version of the IDE.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply, which version of arduino ide should I try?

Comment: If you want to use the old sparkfun files, one contemporary with them.  If you want to create something new, figure out what the latest stable version is, and combine what you can learn from the old sparkfun files and current guidelines for 8 MHz ATmega328p solutions to develop a configuration for an 8 MHz ATmega2560v.  You may also need to set brownout fuses appropriately for 3.3v operation.

Comment: hello, I have used this Megacore and it solved my problem
https://github.com/MCUdude/MegaCore

Comment: @MudassirHussain, then post your solution as answer (yes you can self-answer!), and accept it. This way, 1) The question won't be marked as unaswered anymore b) other users will benefit from you useful information. c) you'll gain reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used megacore bootloaders, and it solved the problem